# I can cope with her in small doses

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 'dose' is a quanity used with drugs that you take when you are ill.

Why does 'in small doses' as in "I can cope with her in small doses" mean 'a litte bit' or 'for some time'?

Answer (score 1):

This is a metaphor. The speaker is comparing her to medicine that doesn't quite sit well. Just like one might get an upset stomach from having two pills instead of one, the speaker implies that "having" (being around/listening to/dealing with) her for too long makes the speaker frustrated/tired/over her.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that "dose" means the amount of medicine.  So this usage is figurative, not literal.

It for a short time.

> I can cope with her, if I only see her for a short time.

"A little bit" would mean exactly the same as "a short time", unless you think it could mean "a small part of her".

The overall implication is that "she has a difficult personality"  For example she could be an overactive child, or a sullen teenager, or a crotchety old lady.

Comment: She might just talk a lot.